# awk output into BC HexToDec calculation

Tags: bash, awk, bc

I am trying to combine `awk` and `bc` in order to create a bash function for quickly converting hex values into a proper format.

```
echo FFFFFF | VAR=$(awk '{print toupper($0)}') | "ibase=16; $((((($VAR - 5) / 100) - 1000)))" | bc
```

I am trying this but I cant seem to get the output of `awk` into the input of the `bc` argument.

Comment: Please provide the expected output given that input as we don't know if you're trying to subtract decimal 100 or hex 100 or do anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you try to do it with `awk` and `bc`, I give you the most convenient option here : `printf`. This allows you to easily convert between decimal, octal and hexadecimal.

```
[bash] % printf "%d" 0xFFFFFF    # hex2dec
16777215
[bash] % printf "%#O" 0xFFFFFF   # hex2oct
077777777
[bash] % printf "%d" 077777777   # oct2dec
16777215
[bash] % printf "%d" 077777777   # oct2hex
0xFFFFFF
[bash] % printf "%#x" 16777215   # dec2hex
0xFFFFFF
[bash] % printf "%#O" 16777215   # dec2oct
077777777
```

The extra character `#` asks printf to insert the prefix `0X` for hexadecimal numbers, and `0` for octal numbers. If you add numbers in hexadecimal form, do not forget to add the prefix `0x` to the number, and `0` for octal numbers.

Ofcourse `bash` has an option to do arithmatic operations.

> **`man bash`**`((expression))`
>    The  expression is evaluated according to the rules described below under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expression is  non-zero,  the return  status  is  `0`; otherwise the return status is `1`.  This is exactly equivalent to `let "expression"`.

This allows you to do all your computations directly. Eg. you want `0xFFFFFF` and subtract decimal `5` and divide by `100` (decimal) and subtract 1000 decimal, you have

```
[bash] % printf "%d" $(( (0xFFFFFF - 5)/100 - 1000 ))
166772
```

Or you can do it all hexadecimal ::

```
[bash] % printf "%d" $(( (0xFFFFFF - 0x5)/0x100 - 0x1000 ))
61439
```

If you now want to store such a number in a variable, you just do

```
[bash] % vardec=$( printf "%d" $(( (0xFFFFFF - 0x5)/0x100 - 0x1000 )) )
[bash] % varhex=$( printf "%#x" $(( (0xFFFFFF - 0x5)/0x100 - 0x1000 )) )
[bash] % varoct=$( printf "%#O" $(( (0xFFFFFF - 0x5)/0x100 - 0x1000 )) )
```

However, decimal is such a special case, that you can get rid of the `printf`:

```
[bash] % vardec=$(( (0xFFFFFF - 0x5)/0x100 - 0x1000 ))
```

The arithmetic evaluation system of `bash` allows you to write any number in any base (up to base 64), and convert it to decimal. Here I convert a base 3 number `3#1212` into the number 50.

```
[bash] % echo $(( 3#1212 ))
50
```

If you wan to use **`zsh`**, you can convert back to any other base :

```
[zsh] % echo $(( [##2]7 ))            # from base 10 to base 2
111
[zsh] % echo $(( [##5]3#1020101100 )) # from base 3 to base 5
1234321
[zsh] % echo $(( [##36]17#415C67A8 )) # from base 17 to base 36
ROFLOL
```

Comment: Thanks this really provided the simplest method with printf.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
 echo FFFFFF |
 awk '{printf "ibase=16\n(((((%s - 5) / 100) - 1000)))\n",toupper($1) ;}' |
 bc
```

(this can be onlined, be sure `|` is last char in line)

in original script

```
echo FFFFFF | VAR=$(awk '{print toupper($0)}')
```

- awk has no input, `VAR` in empty

  ```
  "ibase=16; $((((($VAR - 5) / 100) - 1000)))"
  ```
- `"ibase=... "` is a **command**, this isn't what you want, and it output nothing (save an error).

more complex formulae

```
VAR=$(echo FFFFFF | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
VAR2=..
VARx=...
bc <<EOF
ibase=16
((($VAR - 5) / $VAR2) - $VARx)
EOF
```

where

- `bc <<EOF` is called a heredoc variable will get sbustitued on run.

Comment: Archemar - The toUpper is used to make sure the HEX input is all in uppercase before it goes into the BC otherwise the ouput wont be correct. What you provided doesnt give the right result

Comment: well, is `awk` or `tr` version that is not correct ? `tr` version might bug if you have any file who's name is subset of upper or lower, in that case replace `tr` by `awk`.

Comment: @AdamBen-David does `echo 'ibase=16; (((FFFFFF - 5) / 100) - 1000)' | bc` give "the right result" for you? If not then debug THAT first and don't worry about the pipe through awk for now.

Comment: it give 61439 for me.

Comment: @Archemar with `ibase=16` you're specifically telling `bc` to treat all numbers as hex so just like `fffff` is hex (decimal=16777215), so is `100`  (decimal=256) and ditto for 1000 (4096) and so 61439 is one possible correct output of that script (the other being 61440 depending on the rounding being used since the float result is actually 61439.976562).

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide any sample input or expected output but is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ echo FFFFFF | awk '{print strtonum("0x"$0)}'
16777215

$  echo FFFFFF | awk '{print ((strtonum("0x"$0) - 5) / 100) - 1000}'
166772
```

The above uses GNU awk for `strtonum()` to convert non-decimal strings to numeric values and case doesn't matter:

```
$  echo ffffff | awk '{print ((strtonum("0x"$0) - 5) / 100) - 1000}'
166772
```

or maybe your "100", etc. are intended to be hex too?

```
$ echo FFFFFF | awk '{print ((strtonum("0x"$0) - strtonum("0x5")) / strtonum("0x100")) - strtonum("0x1000")}'
61440
```

Note that the result of the calculation is actually a float and so rounding applies above when printing it as an integer:

```
$ echo FFFFFF | awk '{printf "%f\n", ((strtonum("0x"$0) - strtonum("0x5")) / strtonum("0x100")) - strtonum("0x1000")}'
61439.976562
```

P.S. I started out using the gawk-only `-n` option for this but that should actually be avoided in favor of `strtonum()`, see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nondecimal-Data.