# add zeros as a filling character to the left of your hexadecimal representations

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I use this command to convert bunch of decimal numbers to hexadecimal

```
( echo "obase=16" ; cat file.txt ) | bc
```

However, in the output some values have less than `8` digits:

```
FFF95E13
7613
EE13
16613
6686E13
```

I would like to add zeros as a filling character to the left of your hexadecimal representation if the number of digits is less than `8`. So, it ends up in this format:

```
FFF95E13
00007613
0000EE13
00016613
06686E13
```

I can possibly doing it using python but I was hoping if it is possible to do using `awk` or `sed`? If there is a way to convert to hexadecimal and also add leading zero to make sure all values are `8` digits that would be even better.

Comment: It would be helpful to also include a sample of your input.

Comment: Whenever your question is "I'm using tool A to convert input X to output Y, can I use tool B to then convert output X to output Z" the correct answer is almost always just use awk to convert input X to output Z instead. See [@TomFenech's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51444220/1745001) below.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48748346/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could just use awk instead:

```
awk '{ printf "%08X\n", $1 }' file
```

This prints the first column on each line in uppercase hexadecimal, zero-padded up to 8 characters.

```
$ cat file
111
222
333
444
$ awk '{ printf "%08X\n", $1 }' file
0000006F
000000DE
0000014D
000001BC
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the same with `printf` directly

```
$ seq 100 25 200 | xargs printf "%08X\n"

00000064
0000007D
00000096
000000AF
000000C8
```

`printf` doesn't read from file, you can pipe in the data from a file:

```
$ cat file | xargs printf "%08X\n"
```

or redirect:

```
$ <file xargs printf "%08X\n"
```

or, placed at the end:

```
$ xargs printf "%08X\n" <file
```

doesn't add much to the `awk` solution though...

Comment: Nice, it looks like the input is coming from a file, but maybe that's because the OP thought they needed to make one.